# Why does a java class not terminated while a c++ class is?

Tags: java, c++, class

My teacher asked a question. He asked why is a java class not terminated like a c++ class.
I do not have an answer to his question. Can you help me?

Comment: Why is a semicolon put after declaring a class in c++?

Comment: If you mean the semi-colon at the end of the class definition, that's a holdover from C.

Comment: So what answer should i give to my teacher?

Comment: Because they are different programming languages which are compiled or translated into computer readable code differently? (Guessing)

Comment: The languages were designed differently. That's it.

Comment: I would suggest you to convince your teacher that they two are different languages they have different syntax and the way they work. Its just a coincidence that you find similarity between them .

Answer (score 2):

C++ allows code like

```cpp
class MyClass
{
  ...
} myObject;
```

which makes the class definition part of a statement, and statements end with a semi-colon. Java does not allow this construct.